# Where is Microsoft Bot Framework Connector Service located?

Tags: botframework

I want to make my bot fast to response as possible as I can. So, I want to set App Service region which is near to Connector Service. So, could you tell me where is the region of Microsoft Bot Framework Connector Service?

Answer (score 0):

As of today, Microsoft Bot Service available in below regions,

- East Us 2
- Central US
- North Central US
- South Central US
- West Us
- West Us 2
- Brazil South
- North Europe
- West Europe
- South East Asia
- East Asia
- Australia East
- Australia Southeast
- Japan East
- Japan West

Please refer this [Link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/services/) for more details